# Can you use multiple targets with a single VBO?

Tags: opengl, vbo, buffer-objects

Sample code:

```
1. glGenBuffers(1, &VboId);
2. glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VboId);
3. glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(Vertices), Vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
4. glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
```

So we generate a generic VBO handle, and then we bind it using "GL_ARRAY_BUFFER". Binding it seems to have 2 purposes:

1. We must bind the buffer before we can copy data to the GPU via `glBufferData`
2. We must bind the buffer before we can add attributes to it via `glVertexAttribPointer`

And I think those are the only 2 times you need to bind the VBO. My question is, is there any scenario in which target (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, or GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER) would be different on lines 2 and 3? Or we would want to rebind it to a different target before line 4?

Can we bind multiple buffer targets to a single VBO?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not bind targets to a buffer object. Targets are locations in the OpenGL context that you can bind things (like buffer objects) to. So you bind buffer objects **to** targets, not the other way around.

A [buffer object](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Buffer_Object) (there is no such thing as a VBO. There are simply buffer objects) is just a unformatted, linear array of memory owned by the OpenGL driver. You can use it as source for vertex array data, by binding the buffer to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` and calling one of the `gl*Pointer` functions. These function *only* work with the buffer currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. You can use them as the source for index data by binding them to `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` and calling one of the `glDrawElements` functions.

The functions used to modify a buffer objects contents (`glBufferData`, `glMapBuffer`, `glBufferSubData`, etc) all specifically take a target for their operations to work on. So `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` does its stuff to whatever buffer is currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`.

So there are two kinds of functions that affect buffer objects: those that modify their contents, and those that *use* them in operations. The latter are specific to a source; `glVertexAttribPointer` *always* uses the buffer currently bound to `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`. You can't make it use a different target. Similarly, `glReadPixels` always uses the buffer bound to `GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER`. And so forth. If a function does stuff with buffer objects but doesn't take a target as a parameter, then its documentation will tell you which target it looks for its buffer from.

**Note:** Vertex arrays are kinda weird. The association between a vertex attribute and a buffer object is made by calling `glVertexAttribPointer`. What this function does is set the appropriate data for that attribute, using the buffer object that is currently bound to GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. By "currently bound", I mean bound *at the time this function is called*. So immediately after calling this function, you can call `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)`, and it will change *nothing* about what happens when you go to render. It will render just fine.

In this way, you can use different buffer objects for different attributes. The information will be retained until you change it with another `glVertexAttribPointer` call for that particular attribute.

Comment: Oooh! Thank you! This makes so much more sense now. It was my backwards thinking that was throwing me off.

Comment: Actually, regarding paragraph 3, you're saying `glBufferData` takes a target for their operations to work on... so you're saying it's essentially using `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` as a temporary working buffer then? Why do we need to bind the buffer object to the target and then specify the target again in `glBufferData` then? I essentially tried swapping lines 2 and 3 in my question, and the program doesn't work anymore. I'm trying to understand why you would have to specify the target twice, unless they're doing something different.

Comment: Nevermind.. I think I just figured it out. We bind the buffer object to the target, and then essentially feed the data to that target, and thus indirectly to the buffer object. So both are necessary. Am I thinking about this correctly? The data gets tied to the buffer object, so we can wipe `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` immediately after calling glBufferData without losing anything. I guess it works the same as the attribute pointers.